# How to make a specific thread wait until other threads computes a value required for it in OpenCL

Tags: multithreading, opencl

How to block a specific thread until other threads computes a value required for it in OpenCL.

Comment: see my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689329/is-there-any-way-of-making-a-particular-thread-to-wait-for-other-threads-upon-so/9695169#9695169

Answer (score 1):

If "thread" refers to host code, use blocking read from the device `clEnqueueReadBuffe(buffer,/*wait*/CL_TRUE,...)`. If you created your queue with out-of-order execution, attach an event to the kernel which computes it and wait for that event.

If you need to wait on the device itself, then either switch on `get_*_id(...)` within the kernel and use `barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE)` so that other work-items *in the work-group* (not all work-items) wait at that point. If you need that value for all kernels, then use `enqueueTask` for a single-threaded kernel coming *before* your kernel, and pass the value in a buffer.

Comment: If my kernel needs many of such values and the time of waiting for the value is not exactly same then Is there any other mechanism? Can we use something like  __kernel void wait() {  while(condition_waiting_for) ;  }

Comment: But do you compute those values in a kernel different from the one which needs them? Then you are sure they are computed. Without a more complete description of your problem (than one line), it is hard to say what you need.

Comment: Yes, Other threads do compute the values and one thread has to wait until they say they are done. In this case if I use while(wait_for_a_value) inside kernel it is not waiting, it is executing the rest of the statements.

Comment: Well and why don't you enqueue first kernel which compute what you need, and then the one which uses those computed values?